# Can Azure API management cached based on request payload?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-api-management

Is it possible to use cache based on a key in the request payload?

Eg. let's say we got a json or xml request payload where one of the elements is CustomerId.

Would it then be possible to cache based on CustomerId?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can name your cache variable to something that includes the key value? This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your query properly and am not too late. I think you want to cache only when 'CustomerId' is present in the input OR it contains a certain value.

You can refer to the samples given in the foll link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/policy-expressions-in-azure-api-management/

It will help you to write policy expressions to check the presence or value of a particular field. Then you can cache or ignore based on that.

On a side note, Custom Caching is also something cool to check
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key